# Get current logged in username using Passport JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have created a simple user login application following an online tutorial using Node, Express and Passport. Login works correctly but I would like to get the username of the current logged in user and I can't seem to get this working.

I have the following in my app.js:

```
/// Configuring Passport
var passport = require('passport');
var expressSession = require('express-session');

app.use(expressSession({
  secret: 'cookie_secret',
    name: 'cookie_name',
    proxy: true,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session({
    secret: 'cookie_secret',
    name: 'cookie_name',
    proxy: true,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

From what I read in similar posts, I need to expose the username so that I may use it in other files. I tried to do this in my app.js:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home.jade', { username: req.user.username });
});
```

Home is a route where I would like to use the the username, and I am trying to access the username with an alert like the following:

```
alert(req.user.username);
```

This does not work, the req object is undefined...I'm not sure what I am missing?

---

Managed to get this working. In my app.js I have:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home.jade', { username: req.user.username });
});
```

And then in my /home route I can access the username by doing:

```
req.user.username
```

Comment: You're accesing it incorrectly in Jade, it won't be `req.user.username` but just `username`, so do something like `div #{username}` in your view, and see if it outputs.

Comment: That works when accessing the username in Jade, but how can I access the username in a different javascript file in my project? For example, to use the username and filter records that I get from a collection in a route js file.

Comment: The javascript file isn't parsed by Jade, so you can't. You would have to output the username in the HTML created by Jade, either as a data attribute or in it's own script tag, and then get the data from there in the other javascript file

Comment: Oh I see, i thought there was a way to grab the username in js. I'm trying what you said, so I wrapped the username in a div like this |  <div id='userid'>#{user.username}</div> and then I am trying to access it in my js file using alert(document.getElementById("userid").value); but I keep getting undefined, am I using the div correctly in the jade file?

Answer (score 8):

You are mixing two things, one is the client side, and the other is the server side, both use javascript but for render server side code in the cliente side you could not use directly in the client side. you must pass to the view as you do with

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home.jade', { username: req.user.username });
});
```

here you expose the username variable to the view

In the jade file you should do this

```
alert(#{username})
```

instead of

```
alert(req.user.username)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works when accessing the username in Jade, but how can I access the username in a different javascript file in my project? For example, to use the username and filter records that I get from a collection in a route js file.

Comment: you always can access to the username in a route in the `req object`, just like you do, then pass as an argument of  a controller or model

Comment: You can access  in the client side js and assigned to a variable like this `var username="#{username}";`

Comment: I don't think that works, it just returns the string "#{username}"

Comment: Is not that the idea? To have the username saved on the clientclient side

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
            secret: 'cookie_secret',
            name: 'cookie_name',
            proxy: true,
            resave: true,
            saveUninitialized: true
        })
    );

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

on controller use **req.user**

Comment: Thanks, I already have the serialize and deserialize in a different js file, do I need to add that to app.js? I tried that and it did not work, I still can't access the req.user in my route.

Answer (score -1):

{ username: user.local.username }

Please go with the below link

https://github.com/hnagarkoti/passportauthenticationWorking